# How to notify users when calendar event is updated via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-addin, azure-ad-graph-api

Currently I've been developing a web application that takes advantage of Office 365 Graph API. In my application, it calls the following `Update event` in Graph API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The expected behavior of the API was that each attendee already attending this event should get a notification mail that represents such as "Your calendar event was updated." when the event is updated with the API above. However, the actual behavior was that none of attendees get the notification mail when the event is updated with the API.

I'm wondering if there is a way of getting notification mails for attendees when the calendar event is updated.

FYI: I think if a calendar event organizer manually updates calendar event, attendees can get the notification mail. I would like to realize the same behavior in case of calling Graph API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it in my side by graph api explorer, the attendees received the notifications success. So I think you may not meet the conditions which the document mentioned below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you give the url of the document you quoted?

Comment: @shumach5 The document I quoted is just the [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) you provided in your question.

Comment: Sorry, but let me ask you another question about the part "multiple attendees" in the quote. Does that mean the number of attendees except the organizer should be more than 2?

Comment: @shumach5 In my test, I just add one attendee except the organizer and he received the notification email.

Comment: @HuryShen I have an issue in the same area that I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63480033/1232087) - in case you sometime for a suggestion/comment etc.

Comment: Hi @nam Sorry for the delay. I will take a look your post tomorrow if it hasn't be answered by then. And could you please add `azure-active-directory` tag in your future posts, because `microsoft-graph-api` tag is not my job scope.